# How to set the default user of a VM started by a cloud function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, virtual-machine, user-accounts

My Google VM starts when my Google function triggers the start.
But I would like this VM to start on a specific user instead of default user.

How can I achieve that the VM will start with a specific user not the default one?

Is there any parameter to write in the cloud function to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud and most security experts do not recommend password based logins. This means you should use SSH keys for users.

To specify the user(s) for a new VM instance, specify the username and SSH key in the metadata. For example, using the CLI:

```
gcloud compute instances create VM_NAME \
    --metadata=ssh-keys=PUBLIC_KEY
    ...
```

The PUBLIC_KEY is formatted with the username. That username will be created with the instance. You can specify one or several usernames/ssh-keys.

You can do the same thing using the REST API, SDKs, etc.

These links will provide more details:

- [Add SSH keys to VMs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#add_ssh_keys_to_instance_metadata)
- [Add SSH keys to instance metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/connect/add-ssh-keys#add_ssh_keys_to_instance_metadata)

Comment: I understand that your solution works when you CREATE a new instance. However, if you already have an instance. This instance is already created, but it  is stopped.  You want to start it again . How do you do to start it on a specific user, not the default one ?

Comment: I understand that your solution works when you CREATE a new instance. However, if you already have an instance. This instance is already created, but it  is stopped.  You want to start it again . How do you do to start it on a specific user, not the default one ?
    For instance I use the following script to launch the VM :  
    import google.auth;
    import google.auth.transport.requests;
    creds, project = google.auth.default(); 

    request2 = service.instances().start(project=project, zone=zone, instance='name-of-the-VM');
    response2 = request2.execute()

Comment: @NicolasMATHIEU - Your usage of **user** is confusing. Users log into VMs. VMs do not start as a default user. Unless you are referring to the Compute Engine service account. The code in your comment is using ADC (Application Default Credentials). The Cloud Functions identity is a service account and not a user.

Comment: Hello and happy new year 2022 !

Comment: Yes, I am using a cloud function, and therefore a service account to start automatically a computer engine. When this compute engine is started,  there are scripts automatically launched on this compute engine.  Those scripts are launched with a specific identity and therefore permissions linked to that identity. I would like to change the identity used by the scripts automatically launched when the compute engine is started by the cloud function.

Comment: @NicolasMATHIEU - again what identity are you referring to? Startup scripts run as the root user (called a daemon as in the system process) and not as a **user identity**. You cannot change that and might break things if you did. Edit your question and provide exact details on what you are trying to do. Saying I want to change the identity is not enough. What software, what identity and why?